# twilio video composition : custom grid layout

Tags: twilio-video

I have two concurrent video tracks in my room : the presenter (always present) and the guestspeaker (dynamically changes, blancks allowed). For the records composition, I want to:

- display the presenter video full screen if they are the only one publishing video
- display the presenter video in big format,and to the right, the guestspeaker video in a smaller format.

Here is what I tried ( for a "1280x720" resolution) :

```
var videoLayout = new Dictionary<string, Object>()
             {
                {"main", new Dictionary<string, Object>()
                    {
                    {"x_pos", 0},
                    {"y_pos", 0},
                    {"width", 995},
                        {"height", 720},
                        {"video_sources", new object [] {"video-composer-presentation" } }
                }},
                 {"speaker", new Dictionary<string, Object>()
            {

                {"x_pos", 1000},
                {"y_pos", 210},
                {"width", 280},
                {"height", 200},

                {"video_sources", new object [] {
                    "guest-speaker"
                }}
            }}
                };
```

Good result, but not dynamic( which is normal, dimensions being explicitly set)
[image: fixed layout]
and does not look well centered when there is only one video [image: fixed layout 2]

Then I tried the grid layout :

```
   var videoLayout = new Dictionary<string, Object>()
        {
            {"grid", new Dictionary<string, Object>()
                {
                    {"max_rows", 1},
                    {"video_sources", new object [] {
                    "video-composer-presentation",
                    "guest-speaker"
                    }}
                }}
        };
```

same problem, plus, I don't have control over the dimensions:
[image: grid layout]

[image: grid layout 2]

How can I achieve the desired layout ? thanks